# Resolve hung dpkg --configure -a

Tags: ubuntu

Usiing Ubuntu Server 20.04.

I wanted to install upgrade packages, but it said

```
Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend
```

I killed the process and tried to resume the upgrade. I then ran the following, but that process is now hung.

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.6) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.6) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-81-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sdi2
I: (UUID=f9a3dfb7-e5c9-49d1-b879-937a1a04a18a)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this
```

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: reboot and/or manually remove the lock